# How do i change enum to char? I'm trying to cast it but it gives me an error

Tags: c++, enums, char

so I'm supposed to make a travel program to assist a traveler in knowing where they are (North, South, East, West). And we were supposed to make enum data types for the menu options instead of using char options where the user chooses in which direction they are going and it tells the total distance and distance from home.
I tried to cast the enum but i'm getting this error: expected primary expression before ; token."
This my code.

```
int main(){
    char option_letter;
    int lat1 = 0;
    int lat2 = 0;
    int long1 = 0;
    int long2 = 0;
    double distance = 0;
    int totalDistance = 0;
    enum direction_t {North = 'n', South = 's', East = 'e', West = 'w', Home = 'h', Quit = 'q'};
    direction_t direction = static_cast<direction_t>(tolower(option_letter));
    
    cout <<"Starting home at 0 North/South and 0 East/West, this program shows your position"<<endl;
    cout<<"after travelling 10 miles: north, south, east or west, how far you are from home"<<endl;
    cout<<"and how far you have traveled in total. You can jump home or quit." <<endl;
    
    distance = sqrt(pow(lat2-lat1, 2) + pow(long2-long1, 2));
    totalDistance = (lat1 + lat2) + (long1 + long2);
    while (true){
        cout <<"Location:"<< "longitude:" <<  long1<<" N"<< " latitude:" <<  lat1<<" E"<< " ""distance from home:"<< distance<< " ""distance traveled:"<< totalDistance<<endl;
        cout <<"Choose direction to travel(0 to quit) N)orth, S)outh, E)ast, W)est, H)ome, Q)uit:"<<endl;
        cin << direction_t;
        switch(direction_t){
            case 'n':{
                distance = sqrt(pow(lat2-lat1, 2) + pow(long2-long1, 2) * 1);
                totalDistance = (lat1+ lat2) + (long1 + long2);
                break;
            }
            case 'e':{
                distance = sqrt(pow(lat2-lat1, 2) + pow(long2-long1, 2) * 1);
                totalDistance = (lat1 + long1) + (long1 + long2);
                break;
            }
                
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin << direction_t;` this line is causing the error, rather than your cast

Comment: I changed the operator as i figured that i was using the wrong one, but it's still giving me an error. @Camwin

Answer (score 0):

" ""distance from home:"

U forgot to delete the additional quotation marks

Besides that, you need right facing arrows for cin (>>)

Comment: I changed the operator and deleted the extra quotation marks but it is still giving me the same error. @Cx Vercility

Comment: The additional quotation marks are harmless. Adjacent string literals get concatenated, so that text is equivalent to `” distance from home:”`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

First `cin` should use `>>` instead of `<<`.

Then `direction_t` is a type, `direction` is a variable.

And lastly you can't directly read into a variable of type `direction_t` unless you overload the `>>` operator for cin.

Comment: I did changed the operator but it's still giving me the same error. @Michael Mahn

Comment: You have to fix all the errors I've mentioned.

Comment: when i used "direction" instead of "direction_t", it said "cannot bind std::istream<char>}lvalue to 'std::basic_istream<char>&&'. @Michael Mahn

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the cast is actually implemented correctly, however, you have never initialized `option_letter`, so you're not passing any data to cast. In the context of your problem, you should be passing data from `cin` to `option_letter` via `cin >> option_letter` then convert this to the `direction_t` type.

The reason why you're getting the error is because you're using `direction_t` when you should be using `direction` (this occurs in multiple places in your program), and are using the `<<` operator with `cin` when you should be using the `>>` operator.

Your code should look something like this --

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char option_letter;
    int lat1 = 0;
    int lat2 = 0;
    int long1 = 0;
    int long2 = 0;
    double distance = 0;
    int totalDistance = 0;
    enum direction_t {North = 'n', South = 's', East = 'e', West = 'w', Home = 'h', Quit = 'q'};
    //direction_t direction = static_cast<direction_t>(tolower(option_letter));
    
    cout <<"Starting home at 0 North/South and 0 East/West, this program shows your position"<<endl;
    cout<<"after travelling 10 miles: north, south, east or west, how far you are from home"<<endl;
    cout<<"and how far you have traveled in total. You can jump home or quit." <<endl;
    
    distance = sqrt(pow(lat2-lat1, 2) + pow(long2-long1, 2));
    totalDistance = (lat1 + lat2) + (long1 + long2);
    while (true){
        cout <<"Location:"<< "longitude:" <<  long1<<" N"<< " latitude:" <<  lat1<<" E"<< " ""distance from home:"<< distance<< " ""distance traveled:"<< totalDistance<<endl;
        cout <<"Choose direction to travel(0 to quit) N)orth, S)outh, E)ast, W)est, H)ome, Q)uit:"<<endl;
        cin >> option_letter;
        direction_t direction = static_cast<direction_t>(tolower(option_letter));

        switch(direction){
            case 'n':{
                distance = sqrt(pow(lat2-lat1, 2) + pow(long2-long1, 2) * 1);
                totalDistance = (lat1+ lat2) + (long1 + long2);
                break;
            }
            case 'e':{
                distance = sqrt(pow(lat2-lat1, 2) + pow(long2-long1, 2) * 1);
                totalDistance = (lat1 + long1) + (long1 + long2);
                break;
            }
                
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```